# Why some users are missing "i:0#.w|"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

When I run this script,

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteCollectionURL) 
$web = $site.openweb() 
$siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers 

foreach($user in $siteUsers) 
{        
    if($user.IsSiteAdmin -eq $true) 
    { 
       Write-Host "ADMIN: ", $user.LoginName 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "USER: ", $user.LoginName 
    } 
}
```

I get this output

> ### ADMIN:  i:0#.w|exampledomain\my.user
>
> ### USER:  EXAMPLEDOMAIN\my.user

Any idea why ?

Update:

> New-SPSite 'https://example1.myportal.com/us/SCTest1'
>   -HostHeaderWebApplication 'https://example1.myportal.com’ -Name 'SCTest1' -Description '' -OwnerAlias 'exampledomain\myuser.name' -language
>   1033 -Template 'STS#1'

When I create a site collection like this, I still get same output as above,

> ### ADMIN:  i:0#.w|exampledomain\myuser.name
>
> ### USER:  EXAMPLEDOMAIN\myuser.name

Comment: Have you migrated your SharePoint server from SP2010, or changed the authentication mode to claims?

Comment: @Evariste nope it's not a migrated site :(

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with that kind of difference?

Comment: yes, alerts added by code using standard template are working regardless of i:0#.w| or not in user login, however they won't work if username don't have i:0#.w|, I fixed the issue using .ToUrlEncode but I want to understand why this is happening

Comment: @MHeld https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238544/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-when-added-through-powershell

Comment: You mean _ToEncodedString_, not _ToUrlEncode_ ?!

Comment: @Evariste yes sorry wrote in hurry

Comment: Do you still get new users in wrong format "domain\user"?

Comment: Its not a migrated site, but have you changed the authentication mode to claims like @Evariste asks about? Users without the prefix is a sign that they are from "classic authentication"

Comment: Question to last edit: You create a new HostNamedSiteCollection and specify an Admin there. This one gets the correct Claims tag. How do you add the normal user which misses the tag?

Comment: @AndersAune even I updated my question, it happens when I create a new site collection :)

Comment: @MHeld I am not doing anything else other then running create site collection script, both users are added automatically

Comment: Your own user is added twice? "ADMIN" from the PowerShell-Output means SiteCollection Admin? Maybe you should post the full output of the GetSPAllSPUsers-Function. And also add an image of the HiddenUserList (http://sharepointviews.com/hidden-users-list-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: @MHeld I added wrong script, I just realized so sorry... I updated it now

Comment: The script displays up to 99% correct values. In almost all remaining cases, the users are system accounts. For the rest there are two options: 1. SP2010 Users that are not claims-authenticated (but you already said that the site was not migrated) or 2. Until a user logs into the site he is not recorded in the UserInfo table [...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a lot of testing regarding this issue. I will share my results, even if I cannot provide a perfect answer.

- I am able to reproduce this behavior on several SharePoint machines from SharePoint 2010 to 2016 when creating a SiteCollection.
- The current User gets added as SiteCollection owner with the claim-encoded identity (`i:0#.w|domain\user`). It always gets `ID 1`.
- The domain-identity (`domain\user`) is created with no permissions. It always gets `ID 3`. It is invisible in the [Hidden User List](http://sharepointviews.com/hidden-users-list-in-sharepoint/) of the SiteCollection
- I have found a [VERY old documentation](https://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/440169) with the users which will get created out-of-the-box. Based on this documentation, my thinking is:

  - The SiteCreation-Account still gets ID 1, but is claims-encoded today.
  - **Warning: Pure speculation here!** The domain-account still gets created for historical reasons with ID 3.
- This old [UserInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574853(v=office.12).aspx) table documentation tells us about ID 1 (SC Owner), ID 2 (Secondary owner) and 1073741823 (System). These seem to be still valid, but again: ID 3 is missing.
- A newly created SiteCollection still works if i remove the domain-user (`ID 3`). Not sure if stuff will be assigned to the user if the site is used.
- [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c8f0a0e-612b-4e5d-a768-774bca0e0e25/websiteusers-contains-login-name-twice-on-claims-based-web-app?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) is another unsuccessful discussion about a similar topic.
- If you convert the entire WebApplication with `Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity <URL> -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions`, all ID3 accounts are rewritten to a claims-identity. If you create a new SiteCollection afterwards, ID3 gets a domain-identity again only on the new SiteCollection.